# What is the meaning of "the raised asterisk (*) drops down to a lower level (∗)" in "The TeXbook"?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

At the end of penultimate paragraph on page 132 of the book **The TeXbook**, there is

> the raised asterisk(*) drops down to a lower level (∗).

What is the meaning of that? May you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full quote:

> The three characters `+`, `-`, and `*`
> are called ”binary operations,” because they operate on two parts of
> a formula. For example, `+` is a plus sign, which is used for the sum
> of two numbers; `-` is a minus sign. The asterisk (`*`) is rarer
> in mathematics, but it also behaves as a binary operation. Here are
> some examples of how TeX typesets binary operations when they appear
> next to ordinary symbols:
>
> `$x+y-z$`
> `$x+y*z$`
> `$x*y/z$`
>
> Notice that `-` and `*` produce quite different math symbols from what you
> get in normal text: The hyphen - becomes a minus sign (−), and
> the raised asterisk (*) drops down to a lower level (∗).

No deep meaning: the glyph corresponding to the mathcode of `*` is centered on the formula axis, whereas `*` in text mode will produce a raised asterisk. Which is somehow expected, isn't it?